# Injection model in Visual Component

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, dependency-injection, flex4, parsley

I'm using Parsley framework. I'm trying to inject model in custom visual Tree component;

```
private var _model:Model

[Bindable]

public function get model():Model
{
  return _model;
}

public function set model(value:Model):void
{
  _model = value;
}
```

Build Config:

```
<Object id="customTree" type="{CustomTree}">
  <Property name="model" idRef="model"/>
</Object>
```

Then I have use this tree in mxml:

```
<components:CustomTree
        id="categoriesTree"
        width="100%" height="100%"
        labelField="@title"
        right="0" bottom="0" left="0" top="10"           
        doubleClickEnabled="true"
        maxHorizontalScrollPosition="250"
        horizontalScrollPolicy="auto"
        dragEnabled="true"
        dropEnabled="true"
        dataProvider="{model.dataHolder}"
        />
```

I had try override parent function and I have got an error. (model is null);
 `override protected function dragDropHandler(event:DragEvent):void
    {
      model.action = "drop"
}`

I had set breakpoint in model setter and it was executed but model still null;

Where is the problem?

Comment: The code you've posted made no sense.  Please show all of it.  Furthermore, you're not injecting anything.

Comment: I omit configuration of model in Build Config.

Answer (score 1):

I have found how to fix this problem. If we try inject smth in visual component we should configure it at the same way as we configure visual components.

```
public class CustomTree extends Tree
{

public function CustomTree ()
{
  super();
  this.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, configure);
}

protected function configure(event:Event):void
{
  this.dispatchEvent(new Event ('configureIOC', true));
}
```

`...
}`

Mb someone has some other solution?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that you want parsley to instantiate your CustomTree.
Instead inject model into the view and let CustomTree instance in mxml bind to model.

Config:

```
<Object id="model" type="Model"/>
```

MXML:

```
<mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
[Inject(id='model')]
[Bindable]
public var model:Model;
]]>
    </mx:Script>

<components:CustomTree
        id="categoriesTree"
        width="100%" height="100%"
        labelField="@title"
        right="0" bottom="0" left="0" top="10"           
        doubleClickEnabled="true"
        maxHorizontalScrollPosition="250"
        horizontalScrollPolicy="auto"
        dragEnabled="true"
        dropEnabled="true"
        dataProvider="{model.dataHolder}"
        />
```

You don't need id for injection, you could inject by type, just drop the ids from inject tag and config for model.

Comment: Think I have confused you. I needed to inject model in CustomTree, not in MXML component. I have class - CustomTree.as inside this class I perform some actions with model. Then I have used CustomTree in mxml. And yep, I know that I can inject without id. But thanks for information.